# Save images from SurfaceView and display in imageview, in fragment

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview in a fragment that runs the camera. I can start / stop / take a picture with it, but I can never retrieve the image successfully.

```
jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


            // Create an image file name
            File image = null;
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            try {
                image = File.createTempFile(
                        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                        storageDir      /* directory */
                );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File f = new File(path);
            File file[] = f.listFiles();
            Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
            for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName "+i+" :" + file[i].getName());
            }

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file[0].getAbsolutePath());

            ImageView taken_pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.taken_pic);
            taken_pic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
};
```

The logs will look something like this. The images are piling up even after I relaunch the app having made changes, so I assume they are saving properly (not that I can see them unless I do something like this).

I haven't included any XML as the problem is retrieving the image, not displaying it. What can I do to retrieve these images correctly. And also is there a way / reliable program to view these images from a PC explorer or something? Many thanks.

```
Path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
D/Files﹕ Size: 8
D/Files﹕ FileName 0 :cache
D/Files﹕ FileName 1 :Screenshots
D/Files﹕ FileName 2 :JPEG_20140713_121953_-1379701757.jpg
D/Files﹕ FileName 3 :JPEG_20140713_122054_-1379701757.jpg
D/Files﹕ FileName 4 :JPEG_20140713_123411_-1379701757.jpg
D/Files﹕ FileName 5 :JPEG_20140713_123722_-1379701757.jpg
D/Files﹕ FileName 6 :JPEG_20140713_123833_-1379701757.jpg
D/Files﹕ FileName 7 :JPEG_20140713_124125_-1379701757.jpg
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`

Looks like you're passing a directory name, rather than a file name.  As you can see from your output, the first file in the list is called "cache"; if you look at the disk you'll likely find it's a directory.

You should probably limit yourself to just files whose names end with ".jpg".  One way to do this would be something like [this code](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MiscUtils.java#L42), which uses a simple regex to apply a glob pattern to the list of retrieved files using [File.list(FilenameFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list(java.io.FilenameFilter)).  So you would call `MiscUtils.getFiles(path, "*.jpg")`.

Of course, if there were a directory named "foo.jpg" it would find that as well.  You can eliminate those by testing with [File.isFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()).

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. That's something that seems to have crept in after attempting to re-write it ten times and find solutions.

If I add the filename to the end, or hardcode a filename in then I just get this error: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Which seems to be to do with the bitmapfactory? People mention resetting values when using decodeStream, and apparently decode file does call decodeStream?

Comment: That sounds like a different question, and one that doesn't have anything to do with SurfaceView, ImageView, or fragments.  You may want to write a new question focused on use of SkImageDecoder and Bitmap.

Comment: I disagree.. It's the same code with the same end problem which is producing different errors. I can't re-write the question any differently as I can't give a question a title based off of a solution I don't have. The issue is still retrieving an image from a surfaceview. My solution that I'm trying to fix may not even be the best one.